# Assigning Field Value of Firestore Document to Const on Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to assign the value of a field from a document to a constant to use it across several functions.

```
const stripeAccountId = firestore.doc('orgs/' + subscription.orgId).get()
.then( org => {
    return org.data().stripeAccountId
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `firestore.doc('orgs/' + subscription.orgId).get().then(...)` method returns a `promise`. More info: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Promises are async and you need to assign the `stripeAccountId` inside the arrow function specified inside the `then`.

I don't know where you will use it, but the `stripeAccountId` will only be filled after the promise is resolved.

```
const stripeAccountId = null; 

firestore.doc('orgs/' + subscription.orgId).get().then(org => {
    stripeAccountId = org.data().stripeAccountId;
})

console.log(stripeAccountId); // null

const sufficientTimeInMillisToResolveThePromise = 10000;

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(stripeAccountId); // some-id
}, sufficientTimeInMillisToResolveThePromise);
```